# how to get the row width of a wraptext cell in vba

Tags: excel, vba

is it possiable to get the "array of rows" OR the position of "break row mark(vbCrLf?)" of each row in a "wraptext = True" Cell whose ".Text" is a long String and automatic break into multiple rows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible considering **partial solution for manual line breaks**. The code will looks as follows (for `Activecell`):

```
Sub Solution()

    Dim myArray
    myArray = Split(ActiveCell, Chr(10))

    'return to range cells below activecell
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(myArray) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(myArray)
End Sub
```

Before and after are presented on the picture below:

[image]

Additional tip: instead of `Chr(10)` you could try to use `Chr(13)` if you don't get expected results (other possible dilimiters are: `vbCrLf` and `vbCr`).

Comment: That only _partialy_ answers the question.  Doesn't handle the automatic breaks in a wrapped cell

Comment: KazJaw,thanks for your answer, but still I don't get the result I expected. For example: the Text in `Range("A1") = "Alpha Betha Delta"` (Please note,there is no break row in the String), while the cells `.wraptext =True` make the words break into multiple rows in *APPEARANCE*. So, as I did as your code `myArray = Split(Range("A1"), Chr(10))`, I always get myArray with only one element `myArray(0) = "Alpha Betha Delta"` but not what I expected `myArray(0) = "Alpha";myArray(1) = "Betha";myArray(2) = "Delta";`

Comment: So, do you mean that it is not possible to get multiple rows automatically formatted by `.warptext = True` in vba unless there is manual line breaks in the string?

Comment: in my opinion it's not possible to get rows based on *cell text appearance*.

Comment: One approach could be calculating the linebreaks from `.Columnwidth`,  `.Rowheight`, `LEN`, `Split` and font size.

Comment: @juri, and windows.zoom and screen resolution which could also influence the way text is displayed.

Comment: @KazJaw, your solution works at least for the example, if `myArray = Split(Range("A1"), " ")`.

Comment: Thanks all for who answered and read this question. Finally I thought a way of `first convert the wraptexted Cell into an image`, then `OCR it to get the text with line breaks just like the appearance is`. But, at last this solution was proved not to be a good one.